# SQL Server not visible in Server Explorer

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

If there is a SQL Server 2000 installed on a Server, and i have a VWD Express 2008 on a PC on that network,  what could be the possible reasons for the SQL Server not being visible in the Server Explorer of the VWD ? Both PC's are on the same workgroup.

I also tried keying in the name of the server, and the Login and password, but the databases in that server do not appear in the Dropdown list.

Any suggestions helpful.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Does Visual Web Developer Support SQL 2000? As per my knowledge it does not. Why not use SQL 2005 Express or SQL 2008 Express.
Also you can download SQL Management Studio Express (05/08), Install it on the PC with Visual Web Developer & try to connect to SQL 2000 Machine. If it cannot, It will throw an error which will help you a little more to know the reason.
One last thing (very fundamental..) Is your SQL 2000 running?

Comment: Yes the SQL Server is running. And SQL Server 2000 does work with VWD Express 2005 and 2008

Comment: Please try using management studio to connect to the server (this will give more elaborate error) . When you are connecting via WMD is it throwing any errors. Also have you enabled remote connections in SQL 2000? Disable simple file sharing in the machine with SQL 2000.
Please look in Windows Eventviewer also.

Comment: Also try starting the SQL Server Browser on the SQL 2000 machine